# Joining two DataFrames in with Pandas if one column matches a set of other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to join/merge two Pandas DataFrames, but want to join rows if one column matches *any* of a set of columns on the second frame. Example with two columns (I have eight in my real set).

Multiple matches are not possible for my data.

df1 =

```
    person  fav second_fav
0   adam    xxx cherry
1   bob banana  yyy
```

df2 =

```
    fruit   fruit_val
0   apple   10
1   banana  20
2   cherry  30
```

desired output:

```
    person  fav     second_fav    fruit_val
0   adam    xxx     cherry        30
1   bob     banana  yyy           20
```

Comment: What happens on multiple matches?

Comment: I am OK with any outcome. It could match first or match all (creating multiple rows).

Comment: If there was apple in 0th row, what would have been the fruit_val

Comment: there would be two adams in the final df, one with fruitval 10 and one 30

Answer (score 0):

Merge two dataframes twice using each criteria can help to achieve this

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'person':['adam','bob'],
                           'fav':['xxx','banana'],
                           "second_fav":['cherry','yyy'],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'fruit':['apple','banana','cherry'],
                           'fruit_val':[10,20,30],})
```

First inner join using first criteria

```
result1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['fav'], right_on=['fruit'], how='inner', sort=True)
```

Second join

```
result2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['second_fav'], right_on=['fruit'], how='inner', sort=True)
```

Append the two dataframes

```
result_final = result1.append(result2)

result_final
Out[14]: 
  person     fav second_fav   fruit  fruit_val
0    bob  banana        yyy  banana         20
0   adam     xxx     cherry  cherry         30
```

Comment: this is what I was going to do, but I figured there had to be a better way... perhaps join all the columns into a list and then use a function for the merge?